# Release memory in python when removing item from a list

Tags: python, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have a chunk of python code that processes each element from a list, and then appends the processed element to another list:

```
unprocessed_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
processed_list = []
while len(l1) > 0:

    processed_list.append(process_element(l1[0]))
    del unprocessed_list[0]

    print "Unprocessed size:" ,sys.getsizeof(unprocessed_list)
    print "Processed size:" ,sys.getsizeof(processed_list)
```

I have re-written the code so that after an element is processed, it gets deleted with the `del` statement, and I see in the output that the `unprocessed_list` shrinks in size as the `processed_list` grows.

Does this mean that actual memory will be released, or do I need to do something additionally? Can/should I run the garbage collection manually?

This runs in python 2.7

Comment: I'm not sure if you can garbage collect manually, but python does it for you if there are no other references to the objects

Comment: Yes you can garbage collect manually. See the gc module https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html

Comment: It might be released to be reused by the same process (python will decide when) but it won't be released for the operating system to reuse